# Authorization to control NetworkManager from the Command Line (nmcli) rather than the GUI

Tags: networkmanager, nmcli

With the NetworkManager GUI, my user can connect and disconnect to a VPN at will in an X sesion. But, using the corresponding commands in `nmcli` (in an SSH session) results in authorization errors:

```
> nmcli connection up VPN
Error: Connection activation failed: Not authorized to control networking.
> sudo nmcli connection up VPN
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/###)
> nmcli connection down VPN
Connection 'VPN' deactivation failed: Not authorized to deactivate connections
> nmcli connection show VPN | grep -F 'connection.permissions'
connection.permissions:                 user:[my user]
```

Am I not using the corresponding commands to my GUI actions? Or does NetworkManager just not provide all of the features on its command-line interface that it does in the GUI?

Answer (score 1):

`polkit` was blocking this action, but allowing it for interactive ("active") sessions.

I had a `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d` file that essentially evaluated to:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control")
        return (subject.active ? "yes" : "no");
});
```

And if I wanted to connect to the VPN via an SSH session, I would have to return `yes` unconditionally:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control")
        return "yes";
});
```

Unfortunately, if I don't exercise care, this allows me to shoot myself in the foot over an SSH connection (by disconnecting the physical connection), but [the question about how to prevent NetworkManager from allowing users to disable a particular connection already exists](https://serverfault.com/q/896292/50236).

Comment: thanks, this allows me to disconnect+reconnect my VPN regularly from a cron job, to stay connected to a VPN server that forbids long-lived connections.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39203457/495319 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/681708/comments/11