# Why does the at command not control my wifi via nmcli?

Tags: networkmanager, manjaro, at

I have `at` installed on Manjaro. This works fine:

```
echo "echo 'hi' > /tmp/greetings" | at now + 1 minutes -M
```

But if I try to switch off my wifi after one minute it doesn't do anything:

```
echo "nmcli d disconnect wlp123s4" | at now + 1 minutes -M
```

Running `nmcli` in the terminal works, even from `sh`.

`journalctl` shows me `reason="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control request failed: not authorized"`.

After seeing [Authorization to control NetworkManager from the Command Line (nmcli) rather than the GUI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580555/) I checked my `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/99-manjaro.rules` and see no rules related to NetworkManager. Should I add such a rule?

This is for a desktop computer, not a remote server.

Comment: Do `/etc/at.[allow|deny]` exist? Can a non-root user call `nmcli`? What is the `-M` supposed to do; [the man page I was reading](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at) doesn't have that option?

Comment: `/etc/at.deny` exists with the following entries: `alias, backup, bin, daemon, ftp, games, gnats, guest, irc, lp, mail, man, nobody, operator, proxy, qmaild, qmaill, qmailp, qmailq, qmailr, qmails, sync, sys, www-data`.  `-M      Never send mail to the user`. `nmcli` does work with my regular user with the example I posted above.

Comment: I added 

    polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
        if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control") {
            return polkit.Result.YES;
        }
    });

to `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/99-manjaro.rules` and now it works. I could add this as an answer but I don't know if it's a good general solution. Sorry about the formatting, it seems to be ignored in comments.

Comment: You might be able to debug it some by removing the `-M` then. But yeah sounds like the answer was "policy was forbidding it."